# How to render multiple toasts using map loop in react

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

I am trying to render multiple toasts using .map loop. But it is only the toast with the last element from the loop.

```
var errorCount = { error1: 50, error2: 101, error3: 70, error4: 105 };
    Object.keys(errorCount).map((element, index) => {
      if (errorCount[element] > 100) {
        console.log(element);
        toast.error(
          "Message Title: " + element + "\nErrors: " + errorCount[element],
          {
            autoClose: false,
            toastId: element,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            theme: "dark",
          }
        );
      }
    });
```

The above loop should display "error2" first then "error4". But it is only displaying error4.

Comment: Did you try to add an delay between toast?

Comment: Use "for" or "forEach" instead of map.

Comment: I'm new to react. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @VugarTaghiyev tried with "for" loop. Still same issue.

Comment: trythis:  setTimeout(() => {
//your toast here
}, 100);

Comment: @VugarTaghiyev still same issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried like this and is working for me..

```
import { toast, ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

export default function App() {
  var errorCount = { error1: 50, error2: 101, error3: 70, error4: 105 };
  Object.keys(errorCount).map((element, index) => {
    if (errorCount[element] > 100) {
      console.log(element);
      toast.error(
        "Message Title: " + element + "\nErrors: " + errorCount[element],
        {
          autoClose: false,
          toastId: element,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: "dark"
        }
      );
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

sandbox url - https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-worker-1d8kwi?file=/src/App.js:0-797